# XPages repeat control and button

Tags: xpages, repeat

I have a repeat control on an XPage displaying item summary. To view other details, the user clicks on a button (inside the repeat) which will set a viewScope variable to the rowIndex of the repeat and then open up a modal to display the remeaining item details.

I am unable to set the viewScope variable from the button. It's like it cannot get a handle to the rowIndex.

I have a computed text field set to display the rowIndex at the beginning of the repeat (which works fine).

I'm obviously missing something elementary. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Relevant source code follows:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="50" var="entry" indexVar="rowIndex">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var m = sessionScope.assetMap;
if(m!=null){
m.entrySet()
}}]]></xp:this.value>
<div>
    <small>                 
    <label>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="num">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var itemNum:Number =     parseInt(rowIndex + 1);
itemNum.toPrecision(0);}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    .&#160; Description:&#160; &#160;
    </label>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="desc">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Word(entry.getValue(),"~",3);}]]>    </xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    </small>
</div>
<br></br>
<div>
<xp:button type="button" value="Details ..." id="button2">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{var itemNum:Number =     parseInt(rowIndex + 1);
viewScope.currentItem = itemNum.toPrecision(0);
}catch(e) {
requestScope.errstatus = e.toString();}}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

02/04/2015 Update:

I have isolated the problem to the rendered property of the custom control. The code works if I don't use the rendered property.

The code in the onCLientLoad of my XPage (CSJS) is:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
var sDevice = '';

switch(true){
    case (screenWidth < 768):
        sDevice = 'mobile';
        break;
    case (screenWidth < 922):
        sDevice = 'tablet';
        break;
    case (screenWidth >= 922):
        sDevice = 'desktop'
}

XSP.partialRefreshPost( '#{id:pnlList}', {params: {'sDevice': sDevice}} );
```

});

And the source for my custom control in the XPage with the rendered property is:

```
<xp:panel rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'mobile'}">
        <xc:ccSYS_AppLayoutReq_p xp:key="panelContentFacet">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xc:cc_cartracking_p xp:key="contentFacet"></xc:cc_cartracking_p>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xc:ccSYS_AppLayoutReq_p>  
        </xp:panel>
```

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Dan, maybe try changing your var itemNum:int instead of Number.  Or try removing the type altogether. 

 Also if you wrap rightside of code in print() statements are you getting the expected values in the log?

Comment: Thanks Steve. I don't think it has to do with itemNum:Number because that's being used in the computed field and works just fine there. Also, my try catch is not generating any errors.

Comment: What is the result of print(parseInt(rowIndex + 1)) and print(itemNum) and print(itemNum.toPrecision(0)).  I am thinking that one of them is null or an unexpected result that might give you a clue where it is failing.

Comment: Your example does work for me (I just changed the repeat value and text). I added viewScope.currentItem in a computed text field outside the repeat and it shows after clicking a repeat button row's number.

Comment: When do you render the dialog box? It has to be after full submit when viewScope.currentItem is set properly.

Comment: Knut, I am rendering the modal in the onComplete event. I did not include the code because as far as I am concerned, the scope variable is not being set. I have no idea why it's working for you but not for me. :-(

Comment: Add  `<xp:text
  escape="true"
  id="computedField1"
  value="#{viewScope.currentItem}">
 </xp:text>`
 outside the repeat and look if it shows the proper value when you click such a button.

Comment: Knut, I did. It does not display any value. I've got Leusink's debug control on the page too and I don't see any value for that scope var. I may have to rebuild this page from scratch since the code obviously works for you.

Comment: Yes, it does work for me. Starting from your working example in question and adding piece by piece will be a good way to find the issue. Good luck :)

Comment: Dan, your button use refreshMode="complete", meaning you reload the whole xpage. So you set your viewscope variable, and then reload the whole page. At this time,the value in the viewscope is gone because the page was reloaded! You have to use a partial refresh if you want to use a viewscope variable. If you need a complete refresh, you'll have to use a sessionScope variable

Comment: @Knut I was able to isolate the problem - I have code in the onClientLoad that checks for screenWidth and then does an XSPpartialRefreshPost on a panel which contains the appropriate custom control to load. Those custom controls use the rendered property to display/hide. If I remove the rendered property, the page works as expected. I have edited the post to include the code in onClientLoad and the rendered SSJS.

Comment: How does the panel "pnlList" look like?

Comment: @Knut, it is just the container around the panel with the rendered property: <xp:panel id="pnlList">
  <xp:panel rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'mobile';}">
   <xc:ccSYS_AppLayoutReq_p xp:key="panelContentFacet">
    <xp:this.facets>
     <xc:cc_cartracking_p xp:key="contentFacet"></xc:cc_cartracking_p>
    </xp:this.facets>
   </xc:ccSYS_AppLayoutReq_p>
  </xp:panel></xp:panel>

Comment: My colleague Daniel F experimented on his own with a different XPage and ran into the same issue. He has posted here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328441/action-not-working-with-rendered-property-set-on-custom-control-containing-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set option "Set partial execution mode" `execMode="partial"` in your button.

Look for the whole answer at your colleague's question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28330481/2065611

Comment: That was it! Thanks SO much for spending the time helping us out.