# Action not working with rendered property set on custom control, containing the action button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I came across a weird issue. Here is the situation:

I am using my solution regarding displaying and hiding content based on the screen size: https://xpagesandme.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/diving-into-bootstrap-and-font-awesome-part-3-displaying-hiding-content-based-on-device-type/

So, I set up a custom control, containing the UI for a mobile device. I am using the "rendered" property of said custom control to hide or display it, based on the param value from my post.

Here is the weird issue:

Inside the custom control, I have a button that is supposed to set a scoped variable, do a partial refresh on a panel inside a modal and then display the modal (the call to open the modal is inside the onComplete event of the event handler).

The modal opens, but the scoped variable was not updated.

When I remove the rendered property of the custom control, it works. If I put the rendered property back in again, it doesn't work.

Also, any simple action (i.e. opening a page) won't work. However, CSJS that I put into the onComplete or onStart event of the event handler, will be executed.

Any idea?

P.S.: Here is an example XPage. Remove the rendered property of any of the buttons and the code in the onClick event will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var sDevice = '';

    switch(true){
        case (screenWidth < 768):
            sDevice = 'mobile';
            break;
        case (screenWidth < 922):
            sDevice = 'tablet';
            break;
        case (screenWidth >= 922):
            sDevice = 'desktop'
    }

    XSP.partialRefreshGet( '#{id:pnlList}', {params: {'sDevice': sDevice}});
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:panel
        id="pnlList">

        <xp:button
            value="Button Mobile"
            id="button1" rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'mobile';}">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="pnlToUpdate"
            onStart="alert('onStart')"
            onComplete="alert('onComplete')">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put('sTestValue', 'Button Mobile clicked')}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        <xp:br></xp:br>

        <xp:button
            id="button2" value="Button Tablet" rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'tablet';}">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="pnlToUpdate"
            onStart="alert('onStart')"
            onComplete="alert('onComplete')">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put('sTestValue', 'Button Tablet clicked')}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
        <xp:br></xp:br>

        <xp:button
            value="Button Desktop"
            id="button3" rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'desktop';}">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="pnlToUpdate"
            onStart="alert('onStart')"
            onComplete="alert('onComplete')">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put('sTestValue', 'Button Desktop clicked')}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:panel>
    <xp:panel id="pnlToUpdate">
        <xp:text
            escape="true"
            id="computedField1" value="#{sessionScope.sTestValue}">
        </xp:text></xp:panel></xp:view>
```

Comment: I think you hide the button at the moment the partial refresh tries to run the script in it. Stick to CSJS hiding, if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Frantisek. Looking in Chrome, I can see that the only partial refresh being triggered is that of the button, when I click on it. In addition, the "onStart" and "onComplete" events of the button's event handler fire (I put in alert statements). Just the server side code or simple action is not being executed.

Comment: I do recommend you to read about "JSF phases" in XPages. @Knutt's advice and my comment are about the fact the server updates the model when you click the button (what is, in fact, POST request aka partial refresh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set option "Set partial execution mode" `execMode="partial"` in your button. This will execute button's SSJS first and for sure.

Otherwise it will recalculate the whole page first without an URL parameter `sDevice`. Because `sDevice` is not set the XPage won't render the current part (e.g. desktop-panel) and won't execute button's SSJS. Later on client side, it will execute the partial refresh with URL parameter `sDevice=desktop` and render the desktop-panel but that is too late for executing button's code.

I modified your example from your link. It prints the current URL parameter `sDevice` in panel "pnlList" and prints "button clicked" when button's SSJS gets executed. The button writes a random value to viewScope variable and refreshes the "computedField1". This way you can see what happens on server console when you click the button, refresh page or resize browser window.

As you can test, button works with rendered condition (but won't work without `execMode="partial"`). You can still do a full update instead of the partial refresh in example if you need to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var sDevice = '';

    switch(true){
        case (screenWidth < 768):
            sDevice = 'mobile';
            break;
        case (screenWidth < 922):
            sDevice = 'tablet';
            break;
        case (screenWidth >= 922):
            sDevice = 'desktop'
    }

    XSP.partialRefreshPost( '#{id:pnlList}', {params: {'sDevice': sDevice}} );
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:panel
        id="pnlList"
        rendered="#{javascript:print('param.sDevice: ' + param.sDevice); return true}">
        <xp:label
            value="I am going to be displayed if I am on a mobile device"
            id="label1"
            rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'mobile';}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete"></xp:eventHandler></xp:label>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:label
            value="I am going to be displayed if I am on a tablet device"
            id="label2"
            rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'tablet'}">
        </xp:label>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:label
            value="I am going to be displayed if I am on a desktop device"
            id="label3"
            rendered="#{javascript:param.sDevice == 'desktop'}">
            <xp:button
                value="Label"
                id="button1">
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" execMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        print("button clicked"); 
                        viewScope.currentItem = Math.random();}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </xp:label>
    </xp:panel>
    <br />
    <xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedField1"
        value="#{viewScope.currentItem}">
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

**Update**

Not executing buttons SSJS code is a symptom of the approach itself. The panel "pnlList" gets rendered by default empty. Only after client's load or resize event panel will be partially refreshed and be filled with a device depended content. Unfortunately, the criteria for rendering is fragile as it is only part of partial refresh URL. The button might be work with option `execMode="partial"` but you might run into other issues with this approach.

The better approach is to let the client tell the server what kind of device it is and the server will **save** this information in an viewScope variable and the rendered conditions using the viewScope variable only. This way the server already renders the panel for the current device and will just change it on load and resize event.

Save the parameter sDevice to a scope variable panel's "pnlList" rendered property (return always true) and use this variable in rendered condition in device specific panels:

```
<xp:panel
    id="pnlList"
    rendered="#{javascript:
            if (param.sDevice) {
                viewScope.device = param.sDevice;
            }
            return true}">
    <xp:button
        value="Button Mobile"
        id="button1"
        rendered="#{javascript:viewScope.device == 'mobile';}">
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Knut. I've tried to use "Set partial execution mode" on the desktop button in the example I've posted, but that doesn't work. Unless, I put the button inside a label, then it'll work. Any ideas? Also, I thought because the button has already been rendered, the functionality behind it would have been rendered as well or am I incorrect?

Comment: It does work only if rendered condition is on button's parent/ancestor element. I'd go for a <xp:panel ...> as it doesn't hurt. I couldn't figure out yet why it doesn't work if rendered condition is on button itself.

Comment: Hello Knut, I found a different solution that doesn't require "Set partial execution mode" and it was inspired by your print statement in the rendered property: I simply set a sessionScope variable in there and added a check for both, the param.sDevice and sessionScope.get('') and if either one is set to 'desktop', I display the button.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is a more robust solution and you won't run into similar issues in future anymore.

Comment: Hello Knut, thank you very much for your answer. That is exactly the solution I mentioned in my previous comment. Appreciate your help!